# Python Turtle : How to open a drawing

Tags: python, graphics, tkinter, drawing, turtle-graphics

I have a project that draws turtle on a `Canvas` widget. I already know how to save the drawing but how do you open them. This is an example of what I'm trying to say :

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
... #Just creating widgets

def openDrawing:

...#What goes in here ?

fileMenu.add_command(label = "Open Drawing",command=openDrawing,accelerator="Ctrl+O")

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Depends on how you saved it (which form?)

Comment: @Billal BEGUERADJ As a PostScript file (*.ps)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PostScript file formats   containing image data are [supported](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/pil/pil.pdf) by the  [`PIL`](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/) library. So you can open your turtle `.ps` file like this:

```
import PIL

# Load the .ps file using PIL
ps_file = PIL.Image.open("turtle_file.ps")
ps_turtle = PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage(ps_file)
...
...
# Let us suppose you want to display it on a label
label = Label(image=ps_turtle)
label.image = ps_turtle # keep a reference
label.pack()
```

Comment: Thanks. But can you show me how to edit that image using turtle commands